# Time machine tells me UID or GID have changed but they don't seem so!

Tags: time-machine, unix

Using `tmutil compare` to show the changes between the latest snapshot and the current state of the disk, I am told that most of, if not all, my files had their UID or GID changed. Here is one line from the output of `tmutil compare` as an example:

```
! 85.9K   (UID, GID)            /Volumes/A/path/to/file
```

But `ls -n` does not show me that (501 is the logged user, and 20 is group `staff`):

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 501  20  88007 Dec  4  2017 /Volumes/MyTimeMachine/Backups.backupdb/MyMachine/Latest/A/path/to/file
-rw-r--r--@ 1 501  20  88007 Dec  4  2017 /Volumes/A/path/to/file
```

The two files look exactly identical but Time Machine thinks they differ. Why?!?

Background: I had a system disk, let's call it A, in my MacPro, with a Time Machine backup. For speed, I created a new system disk B on SSD, I moved some files from A to B but I will keep most of the data on A because B is too small. So now I would like to continue using the same Time Machine backup. The recommended way to do that is the command-line utility `tmutil` for that: I did

```
sudo tmutil inheritbackup /Volumes/MyTimeMachine
sudo associatedisk -a /Volumes/A /Volumes/MyTimeMachine/Backups.backupdb/MyMachine/Latest/A
```

It worked: I can browse the snapshots of disk A back and forth in time with the Time Machine interface. However, before starting a backup, I checked with `tmutil compare` what Time Machine thinks has changed on disk A, and that's the discussion I started this question with.

Comment: The current state of the disk and the last snapshot of it will always differ. There are constant I/O processes reading from and writing to your disk.

Comment: UID/GID have no reason to change, especially not on the scale I am seeing. There is something systematic going on but I don’t understand what!